# Problem with Qt Creator menu bar

Tags: qt-creator

I've just installed Qt Creator and all the options of the main menu bar are invisible, but I can click them. How to fix this?

[Link to Postimg.org](http://postimg.org/image/ohjq0i575/)

[image: Postimg.org Image]

Comment: This question is already a year old. So maby an update might solve the issue.
If not, this are two things I would suggest you to try out:
1. Close QtCreator, rename the file ~/.config/QtProject to ~/.config/QtProject-Copy and see, whether the default settings solve the issue
2. Open Qt Creator, Press [Alt]+[T], then [O]  to open the options dialog, choose a different style.